# Sumar una propiedad de varias clases

Tags: javascript, nodejs, poo, objeto, javascript-objeto

Es un proyecto en javascript, el código que tengo es el siguiente, es una prueba de lo que quiero hacer para poder implementarlo en un futuro en algún proyecto. El problema que tengo es que no me suma la propiedad de las instancias de la clase "Pirata" y poder almacenar el resultado en un variable, es decir, quiero coger la propiedad de cada instancia de la clase "Pirata" y sumarlas todas y hacerla un resultado solo, lo tengo hecho con un bucle for, pero cuando lo ejecuto me sale por consola [object Object], identifica que es un objeto, pero no su propiedad, que es lo que me interesa. Seria de gran ayuda que me resolvierais esta duda!! :):)

```js
class Pirates {
  constructor(strongPower) {
    this.strongPower = strongPower;
  }
  currentPirates() {
    let sp = this.strongPower;
    let current = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < pirate.length; i++) {
      current = current + sp;
    }
  }
}
currentPirates();

let newPirate1 = new Pirates(100);
let newPirate2 = new Pirates(200);
let newPirate3 = new Pirates(300);
let newPirate4 = new Pirates(400);

let pirate = [newPirate1, newPirate2, newPirate3, newPirate4];
let numPirates = pirate.length;
document.write(`El numero de piratas es: ${numPirates} <br>`);
```

Comment: Hola que error te sale por consola?

Comment: No entiendo... lo que pretendes hacer es tener 4 piratas, meterlos en un array y luego sumar el `strongPower` de cada uno? Es decir, para tu ejemplo esperas que devuelva 1000 (100+200+300+400)?

Comment: te aconsejo que eches mano a algún tutorial de programación orientada a objetos para JS

Answer (score 1):

falla de concepto, el error es creer que una clase se puede sumar, el otro que para acceder a un elemento de la clase este debe ser instanciado.

finalmente no hay por que hacer un loop si solo necesitas sumar

```js
class Pirates {
  strongPower;
  constructor(strongPower) {
    this.strongPower = strongPower;
  }
}

let newPirate1 = new Pirates(100);
let newPirate2 = new Pirates(200);
let newPirate3 = new Pirates(300);
let newPirate4 = new Pirates(400);

let numPirates =(newPirate1.strongPower+newPirate2.strongPower+newPirate3.strongPower+newPirate4.strongPower);
document.write(`El numero de piratas es: ${numPirates} <br>`);
```

podemos ver que cada ves que llamas a la clase se genera un objeto independinete y despues sumas cada valor de la variable para obtener un total

Comment: Pero cuando se trata de una lista de 100.000 instancias de clase, seria muy tedioso ir uno a uno de manera manual para poder sumar la propiedad de todas las clases...

Answer (score 0):

Para llamar a currentPirates() deberías hacer newPirate1.currentPirates(), porque es una función de la clase (no es una función global).

Luego tu función currentPirates() recorre una lista, esta lista la declaras como variable global. Si bien esto es posible, no es recomendable. Ya que haces que la ejecución de esta función dependa de una lista a la cual puede no tener acceso según como implementes tu código.

Podrías crear algo así:

```js
class Pirates {
  constructor(strongPower) {
    this.strongPower = strongPower;
  }
}

class Barco{
  lista = [];
  
  Add(pirata){
    this.lista.push(pirata);
  }
  
  GetCantidadPiratas(){
     return this.lista.length;
  }
  
  GetstrongPowerTotal(){
    let current = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.lista.length; i++) {
      current += this.lista[i].strongPower;
    }
    return current;
  }
}

let barcoPirata = new Barco();
barcoPirata.Add( new Pirates(100) );
barcoPirata.Add( new Pirates(200) );
barcoPirata.Add( new Pirates(300) );
barcoPirata.Add( new Pirates(400) );


console.log(`El número de piratas es: ${barcoPirata.GetCantidadPiratas()}`);

console.log(`La fuerza total es: ${barcoPirata.GetstrongPowerTotal()}`);
```

#### upadate: Solución con una sola clase pirata, usando una lista static

nota: Esta solución si bien la pide el OP, en lo personal no me gusta.

```js
class Pirates {
 static lista = [];
  constructor(strongPower) {
    this.strongPower = strongPower;
    Pirates.lista.push(this);
  }
  
   static GetCantidadPiratas(){
     return Pirates.lista.length;
  }
   static GetstrongPowerTotal(){
         let current = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < Pirates.lista.length; i++) {
      current += this.lista[i].strongPower;
    }
    return current;
  }
}



new Pirates(100);
new Pirates(200);
new Pirates(300);
new Pirates(400);


console.log(`El número de piratas es: ${Pirates.GetCantidadPiratas()}`);

console.log(`La fuerza total es: ${Pirates.GetstrongPowerTotal()}`);
```

Comment: Y podria hacer que todos los metodos esten en una sola clase, en la de "Piratas", por ejemplo?

Comment: @alexdeveloper Al final agregue un código, con todo en una sola clase